# How to group multiple words that together convey one particular meaning using word embedding NLP

Tags: nlp, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I am working on a NLP project and I am new to this field. I am doing WORD EMBEDDINGS in KERAS. I wanted to embed multiple words, (which together convey a particular meaning) together as one word.

For eg:  Copper pipe, both of them together convey one meaning but as separate words looses the context completely.

Similarly, Mechanical Engineer, hot water, N-Dimension Vector space  etc

How do I do it so that together they get ONE embedding vector ??

Answer (score 0):

You are describing noun phrases. Use any part of speech tagging library, preferably in tree mode, to harvest noun phrases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tokenize n-gram structure also. That will ensure that n-grams, in your case specifically bigrams ("Copper" "Pipe" --> "Copper Pipe" ) will be assigned the same tokens.